# array_search() doesn't match on the last key

Tags: php, arrays, search

I am trying to create a function that dynamically grabs all the children pages of a specific page. Then it will check what the current page is, and grab the next three pages to show as a preview.

The last page ID is 6120.
You can hard code the $pagesArray() and the $lastKey and $matches to see the result.

```
$pagesArray(
[0] => 6135
[1] => 6139
[2] => 6176
[3] => 6178
[4] => 6163
[5] => 6152
[6] => 6167
[7] => 6183
[8] => 6201
[9] => 6190
[10] => 6172
[11] => 6197
[12] => 6205
[13] => 6154
[14] => 6120
);
$lastKey = 14;
$matches = 14;
```

When I go to the last page, the page ID is 6120 which is the 14th ID of the array.
It should return the first 3 page ID's but instead it won't match. Please help. Here is the code.
For reference, $matches == $lastKey should be the part of my conditional that sets the $nextPagesArray(). They are both 14, but it doesn't match.

```
function getNext3PortfolioPages(){

global $post;

$currentPage = $post->ID;
$last = '';
$lastKey = '';
$pagesArray = array();
$nextPagesArray = array();

$args = array(
    'child_of' => '6115',
    'offset' => $post->ID
);

// get all the page id's that are children of page 6115
$result = get_pages($args);

// add the page id's to the $pagesArray
foreach ( $result as $page ){
    array_push($pagesArray, $page->ID);
}

//find the last page id in the array
$last = end($pagesArray);

// find the index of the last array value
$lastKey = key($pagesArray);

// find the index of the current page displayed
$matches = array_search($currentPage, $pagesArray);

// check to see if the current page index is the same as the end of the array 
// and set up the $nextPagesArray with the next 3
if ( (int)$matches == (int)$lastkey ) {
    //print_r('1');
    //print_r($pagesArray);
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[0]);
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[1]);
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[2]);

} elseif ( $matches == $lastkey - 1 ) {
    //print_r('2');
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[$lastKey]);
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[0]);
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[1]);

} elseif ( $matches == $lastkey - 2 ) {
    //print_r('3');
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[$lastKey - 1]);
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[$lastKey]);
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[0]);

} else {
    //print_r('4');
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[$matches + 1]);
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[$matches + 2]);
    array_push($nextPagesArray, $pagesArray[$matches + 3]);

}

return $nextPagesArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your array to "wrap around" so-to-speak, you can just extend your array using the first three elements like this:

Input:

```
$pages=[6135,6139,6176,6178,6163,6152,6167,6183,6201,6190,6172,6197,6205,6154,6120];
```

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c158ac7a49cc8f54373e48ee92789e163c4a59dd)):

```
$extended_pages=array_merge($pages,array_slice($pages,0,3));

if($x=array_search(6120,$pages)){
    $next3=array_slice($extended_pages,$x+1,3);
    var_export($next3);
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 6135,
  1 => 6139,
  2 => 6176,
)
```

This will save you having to do a bunch of conditional checks and it will work regardless of the page number used in the search (so long as the page number exists in the array, of course).

Comment: @JohnDavid Happy to help.  If you would like me to clarify anything, just let me know.

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, i'm intermediate at best, but i didn't even think about this, it makes perfect sense. No conditionals just rolls through the end to the front.

Comment: @JohnDavid  I've only become really active on SO in the last 3 months, but the amount that I've learned is amazing.  This place is the best for picking up clever techniques and sharing best practices.  Pay it forward.  Happy coding.